# How to wait until for "particular text" is present that to using insensitive/Ignore case?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath("path"), "Text"));
```

The above command executes successfully  only if the text in the locator is exactly same as "Text" but fails when the text in the locator is Case Insensitive . For Example Found text is "TEXT" or "tEXT" or etc...

I want my condition to compare it ignoring case sensitive. Any suggestions... please.

Answer (score 5):

#### We have simple simple solution for this

 Either you can convert your Expected variable and Actual variable to Lowercase or Uppercase before asserting them, so your code should like below.

```
String expectedValue = "abcd";
String actualValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath")).getText().toLowerCase()

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath("path"), actualValue));
```

Comment: How does this compare without case sensitivity? If the text in the "path" Element is anything other than lowercase it will return false and fail.

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of [textToBePresentInElement](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java) is as follows:

```
  public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> textToBePresentInElement(
    final WebElement element, final String text) {

    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          String elementText = element.getText();
          return elementText.contains(text);
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          return null;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return String.format("text ('%s') to be present in element %s", text, element);
      }
    };
  }
```

If you create a new implementation like this:

```
  public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> loweredTextToBePresentInElement(
    final WebElement element, final String text) {

    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          String elementText = element.getText().toLowerCase();
          return elementText.contains(text.toLowerCase());
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          return null;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return String.format("text ('%s') to be present in element %s", text, element);
      }
    };
  }
```

And use the new implementation it will ignore the case of the text sent in and work as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal by converting text into small case first before comparing them.

For example, if you are using Python:

```
xpathString = "ABC"
newXpathString = (xpathString.lower()) //newXpathString = 'abc'
```

Your new script logic flow will be:

- Convert TEXT, tEXT into text
- Write your xpath expression with newly converted strings

But there IS a logical flaw here:

- Xpath expression is supposed to be UNIQUE, converting texts into lower case would eliminate uniquess of a string; not to mention you are adding more lines to your code, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I created my owne ExpectedCondition:

```
 public static  void WaitForElementTextVisible(final WebElement elementFindBy, String text)
{

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(LocalDriverContext.getRemoteWebDriver(), 30);
  //  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(elementFindBy, text));
        wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                if(elementFindBy.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(text))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
}
```